# DevExpress & C# : Validate RepositoryItemLookUpEdit cell after choosing value

Tags: c#, validation, repository, devexpress

I have a GridView in which i have this column :

```
bandedGridColumn.ColumnEdit = InitEdit_Material();
```

Here is the InitEdit_Material method :

```
public static RepositoryItemLookUpEdit InitEdit_Material()
{
    RepositoryItemLookUpEdit riMaterial = new RepositoryItemLookUpEdit();

    riMaterial.Columns.Add(new LookUpColumnInfo("ID", "ID"));
    riMaterial.Columns.Add(new LookUpColumnInfo("CustomsMaterial.Name", "Name"));

    riMaterial.DataSource = Service.GetAll(svc.EntityTypeToGet.Material).Data.All_Material;

    riMaterial.DisplayMember = "MaterialFullname";
    riMaterial.ValueMember = "ID";

    riMaterial.AutoSearchColumnIndex = 1;
    riMaterial.BestFitMode = BestFitMode.BestFitResizePopup;
    riMaterial.NullText = "";


    return riMaterial;
}
```

This is what it looks like :

[image]

I want to perform some actions (set other cell's value based on current cell value) whenever user choose a new value in this cell, but the problem is all the possible event i know only fires once the cell lost focus, i've tried :

```
private void vwVD_ValidatingEditor(object sender, BaseContainerValidateEditorEventArgs e)
{
    if (vwVD.FocusedColumn.Name == "colMaterialID") 
        MessageBox.Show("only show when focus lost");
    return;
}

private void vwVD_CellValueChanged(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.Name != "colMaterialID") return;

    MessageBox.Show("only show when focus lost");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [`GridView.CellValueChanging`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CellValueChangingtopic) event:

```
private void vwVD_CellValueChanging(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (vwVD.FocusedColumn.Name == "colMaterialID")
    {
        //Perform some actions. Use e.Value.
    }
}
```

Comment: hey man, sorry for the late reply, this works fine to me, thanks